# prove the set of all finite unions of all intervals in [0,1] is an algebra but not a sigma-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

let's say

$\mathbf{A}=${all intervals contained in [0,1]} and

$\mathbf{B}$={all finite unions of elements of $\mathbf{A}$}

proving that $\mathbf{B}$ is an algebra is mostly straightforward, except i'm not sure how to prove that $\emptyset \subset \mathbf{B}$. And for that matter, how do I even prove that $\emptyset \subset \mathbf{A}$? Can I just say the 'interval' for example $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ it not actually an interval is therefore $\emptyset$ ?

To prove that $\mathbf{B}$ is *not* a sigma-algebra, do I need to construct a countable union or intersection of subsets of $\mathbf{B}$ and show that it's not contained in $\mathbf{B}$? Can I say that $\bigcup_{j \in \mathbf{N}} [\frac{1}{2j+1},\frac{1}{2j}] \notin \mathbf{B}$ (where $\mathbf{N}$ is the set of natural numbers) and thus $\mathbf{B}$ is not closed under countable union and therefore cannot be a sigma-algebra?

Comment: The empty union (the union of no sets of $\mathbf A$) is the empty set. Since $0$ is finite, $\emptyset\in\mathbf B$.

Comment: Open sets behave nicely with union so I would think about an intersection. Have you seen the construction of the Cantor set? It's not the union of intervals because its Lebesgue measure is null.

Comment: is my use of closed sets in the proof above incorrect though?